# sendmail with text formatting for email/gmail

Tags: perl, text, formatting, sendmail, text-formatting

Is it possible to write rich/html text-formatting email that will be recognized by the gmail.
(e.g. bold text, italic text etc)

I use sendmail en perl to send an email.

Best regards

Serg.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but better use [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MIME-Lite/lib/MIME/Lite.pm).
See the [examples](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MIME-Lite/lib/MIME/Lite.pm#Send_an_HTML_document..._with_images_included!).

Comment: Here I found it. Here is how you can do it with sendmail http://alma.ch/perl/Mail-Sendmail-FAQ.html